# How to match index macro from another file vba

Tags: excel, vba, match

I would like to create a macro that will retrieve my data from another file.  I have more columns in another file than in my working file.  Let's say between price, mob, exp and mob price, freq, exp, mob.  I would only like to get the data from the columns that I need.

This is my code im begginer really.

```
    Dim e as long, g as long, g as long
    Set tempwb = workboooks("location", True, True). Workseets(sheets1). Range("A1:D1")
    
    Set dataWB = workboooks("location", True, True). Workseets(sheets1). Range("A2:D2" )
    
    E= Cells.(rows.count, ("D").end(xlUp).Row
    G =1
    
    For f = 2 to e 
        If isempty(Cells(f, "D")) = False then
            Cells(f, "D") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(tempWb,application.Match(Range("A2", dataWb, 0))
            G=g +1
        End If 
    Next f
End sub
```

I got error if i remove cells(f, "D") this put nothing On sheet. Could you help me guys correct my code

Comment: If you work with multiple worksheets or workbooks you need to specify for every `Cells`, `Range`, `Columns`, `Rows` object in which workbook and worksheet it is supposed to be. If you just write `Cells(f, "D")` VBA cannot know in which workbook/worksheet that is. If you write `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(f, "D")` it is clear. Fix that. • Also that if you get errors you need to tell us in which line and what the error message is.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ how about only importing required fields using `Pivot Table` in some new sheet (but that needs referring to sheet too, of course)